# jQuery autocomplete minLength not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

First of all, I have been looking through tens of 'solutions' on SO already, however those have not brought a solution for my fairly similar question.

I use autocomplete in combination with ajax to get JSON from an API call. This works fine, except for the amount of calls that are being made. After a short test, I discovered my 'minLength' is not working. The function triggers after every keypress. The API holds tons of records, so this is a rather big issue.

My code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.autocomplete-custom-append input').autocomplete({
        minLength:10,
        lookup: function(query, done){
            $.ajax({
                url:'/wp-content/themes/inf-child/apicall.php',
                type:'post',
                data:{'search_query': query},
                success:function(response){
                    console.log('call made');
                    done(JSON.parse(response));
                },
                error:function(xhr, status, error){
                    console.log(xhr.status + ':' + xhr.statusText); 
                    done({});
                },
            });
        },
        appendTo: '.autocomplete-suggestions',
    });
});
```

No rocket science, but I think I am overlooking another issue.

**additional information**
This code is running inside a child theme on Wordpress. Should not be a factor, but who knows what secrets may hide in that garbage that WP can be sometimes.

What have I tried so far? Beside looking through alot of posts, I also tried to change my 'lookup' function into a 'source' function, but then I ran in other issues. I do also use a 'onSelect' function in the original code, but that only manages the changes the styling after selecting a result.

Many thanks in advance! :)

**EDIT**

Belore is the JSON i recieve from the form.php

{"suggestions":[{"value":"DEMO DATA","data":{"accountid":"12345-12345-12345","name":"DEMO DATA","emailaddress1":"email@email.com","address1_postalcode":"1234 BA"}}

received from `$output = ['suggestions' => $array];` where `$array` is a foreach function from the API call. This part works fine. I get the data.

The form itself is build with Gravityforms, en de HTML is al follows:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_1" action="/form/">
    <div class="gform_heading">
        <h3 class="gform_title">CRM form</h3>
        <span class="gform_description">Test form for crm dynamics integration</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gform_body"><ul id="gform_fields_1" class="gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below"><li id="field_1_1" class="gfield autocomplete-custom-append gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible ready"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_1">Zoek jouw school<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_1" id="input_1_1" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off"></div><div class="autocomplete-suggestions"><div class="autocomplete-suggestions" style="position: absolute; max-height: 300px; z-index: 9999; width: 524px; display: none;"><div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-index="0">RK BS <strong>De Vaert</strong> || 5171 KJ</div></div></div></li><li id="field_1_2" class="gfield crm-data-input crm-emailaddress1 gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_2">Emailadres<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div></li><li id="field_1_3" class="gfield crm-data-input crm-address1_postalcode gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_3">Adres<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_text"><input name="input_3" id="input_1_3" type="text" value="" class="medium" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></div></li>
                            </ul></div>
        <div class="gform_footer top_label"> <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1" class="gform_button button" value="Submit" onclick="if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]){return false;}  window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]=true;  " onkeypress="if( event.keyCode == 13 ){ if(window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]){return false;} window[&quot;gf_submitting_1&quot;]=true;  jQuery(&quot;#gform_1&quot;).trigger(&quot;submit&quot;,[true]); }"> 
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="is_submit_1" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_submit" value="1">

            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_unique_id" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="state_1" value="WyJbXSIsIjJiYjc0ODA2MWQ3MmFlMDRmMDFkYjg5YTc0ZTZmMDRjIl0=">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_target_page_number_1" id="gform_target_page_number_1" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_source_page_number_1" id="gform_source_page_number_1" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="gform_field_values" value="">

        </div>
</form>
```

I assume the above has nothing to do with the particullar problem though...

Comment: Check the 'view page source' to ensure the `minLength` appears within the javascript as expected, and if not, try to clear browser cache and then reload.

Comment: @PaulT. it does appear. The 'basics' have been checked :)

Comment: It would help if you were able to give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can see all of the relevant code to try figure out whats going wrong. We can only help to debug what we can see :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I added some of the rest of the code, but I cannot imagine it has anything to do with the issue :(

Comment: Maybe not, but it means we have a complete and reproducible example to work with - that means we can recreate the problem and see it in action, which helps us to troubleshoot it. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how that can help you get help for future questions too :)

Comment: OK, I've created a test with the code you provided and it's working, so there must be something somewhere else that's causing the problem. I suggest you create a minimal *reproducible* example as described in the link above, because if the error isn't in the code you've given us then we can't find it :) Try getting it to work in a simpler example with just one input and without ajax first - the first rule of debugging is to simplify! Strip out all possible complications and concentrate on just the problematic code.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Hmm, strange. I will minify the code. Thanks for your help and feedback. Really apprreciate it!